# bug in the CTAN version of aux-renum.el

Tags: latex

Emacs has been my LaTex editor for several years.  Along with AucTex, I have been using the label/ref management utility for emacs supplied by aux-renum.el.  It's available on the CTAN archive at

[aux-renum.el](http://tug.ctan.org/support/emacs-modes/aux-renum.el)

However, when I fired it the other day I ran into an error:

invalid read sytax: "#"

If anyone has updated the aux-renum package to work with the current version of emacs, I would greatly appreciate knowing how to get a copy of a working version.  Thanks in advance.

Comment: Does your TeX document use the `hyperref` package?  If so, turn it off and try `aux-renum.el` again.

Comment: How do you "fire" it exactly?  Have you checked you haven't edited it (or another config file) inadvertently?

Comment: Let me be more explicit about the issue: if yr LaTeX document has `\usepackage{hyperref}` in it, then the `.aux` file has a format that `aux-renum.el` does not expect (no surprise: pdf was not a thing when it was written).  This causes `aux-renum.el` to write garbage to a temporary buffer on which it does an `eval-buffer` and this provokes the read error.

Comment: @FranBurstall Many thanks!  Disabling hyperref solved my problem.

Comment: @JeanPierre thanks for responding.  Firing up meant loading the file aux-renum.el and invoking the command aux-renumber-single.

Comment: @franburstall that would make a good answer! That sort of interaction can be very tricky to track down

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Short answer: your TeX document is using the `hyperref` package.  Simply turn it off by commenting out the

```latex
\usepackage{hyperref}
```

line and try to use `aux-renum.el` again.

Longer answer: `aux-renum.el`parses the LaTeX document's `.aux` file and writes what it finds into a temporary buffer on which it runs `eval-buffer`.  Meanwhile, `hyperref` completely subverts the `.aux`, redefining `\newlabel` among other things.  Put the two together and `aux-renum` writes garbage into the temporary buffer and then tries to `read` it.  Hence the error.

It is hard to blame `aux-renum` for this: it was written in 1995 before PDF took off and `hyperref` became almost mandatory.